# Video conferencing server architecture

Tags: architecture, sip

I am developing a video conference application with the following requirements:

- Audio works like call conference, where all participants may talk at the same time.
- However, video works like broadcasting, where only one designated client broadcasts one video to the rest.

Clients will be Android devices.

One way of doing this is to use a SIP stack (e.g. Asterisk) and use its conference call capabilities; however the video conference part of Asterisk looks pretty undeveloped. Also, there might be some issues using SIP, as the app will be used over 3G and/or restrictive firewalls.

Another way is to use streaming media server like Wowza, which while it is impressive on live video streaming, it does not seem to have a conferencing capabilities.

Is there a better way to approach this? It seems that this use case is pretty common and there are various similar solutions for desktop apps.

Comment: I hope you became a millionaire around the current health crisis!